# Accessing an image in the projects resources?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I access an image during run time that I have added to the projects resources?

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
if (value) {
    picBox1.image = Resources.imageA;
}
else 
{
    picBox2.image = Resources.imageB;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something.Image = Namespace.ProjectName.Properties.Resources.ImageName;