# Visual C# form backgroundImage

Tags: c#, image, icons, exe

I have used a JPG for backgroundImage for an application form.
My question is that do I always need the JPG with the exe program?

So if I give my exe program to another user, the person won't be able to view the backgroundImage if I dont provide the JPG file?

another question is regarding the icons that I use for the program (exe icon and an icon that displays at top of your program).. are these icons stored in the program? or i need to provide the icon file(s)?

sorry i only have a machine and don't have someone to test for me.

cheers,
D

Comment: How are you referencing the image.  Also, what GUI technology are you using, WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add image as a resource for the Application. If you add it simply as a file link e.g. C:\somelocation as soon as that changes you loose teh image.

If its added as a resource then it is inculded with the build and always present for the Application.

To know more on how to do this look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p8.html

Answer (score 1):

An easy test would be to put the .exe in a separate folder and try to launch it.

For the JPG it depends how you refer to it in your program, if it is a resource that you added it will be in the executable.

The icon should be in the executable already.

Comment: This wouldn't work if somehow the program used an absolute path to the image.  Of course, you could always try moving the image.  Good advice, but no upvote on this because it only mentions how to test whether there is a problem, not how to solve the problem if it existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the .jpg file as a resource in your application, which results in it being compiled into the .exe itself, giving you one less file to distribute.

Check out [Accessing an image in the projects resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106396/accessing-an-image-in-the-projects-resources)